# Advice on how to structure LSTM input Data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've built model to predict the price of a particular stock. I have all the hourly candle data for this stock for the last three years, as well as additional features.

Right now, the input vector shape is [206,72,9]. The 72 being three days, and the 9 being the number of features.

My first question is, is there an optimal amount of candles to pass in for the second dimension? Would [618,24,9] potentially improve the results?

My second question is, right now the data [1,2,3,4,5,6] is passed in as [1,2,3],[4,5,6], which contains no overlapping hours. Would changing this to [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6] also potentially improve the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer both your questions concurrently.

It is possible that more data (both in terms of greater time steps and overlapping series **might** improve the results - however there are situations where too much data can also be a detriment to your forecasts.

One of the disadvantages of using LSTM models for time series forecasting is that they tend to carry forward too much volatility from previous time steps into the subsequent forecasts - which can make this model an unsuitable candidate for analyzing trend data - they are best used for time series that are highly volatile. Therefore - in answering your question - it is possible that too much data could be as bad as not having enough data - it all depends on the time series under analysis.

In this regard, you should consider the price trend of your stock. If it is a stock that is highly volatile, e.g. a small-cap stock, then an LSTM model might work well. However, if it is a large-cap stock, or one that has a clear trend in the data over time, then LSTM might prove unsuitable.

You might find [the following article](https://towardsdatascience.com/are-lstms-always-effective-at-time-series-analysis-a-case-study-of-oil-prices-97644f716a1c) regarding the use of LSTM to forecast oil prices of use - it is evident that with a strong trend in the data, LSTM proves too volatile to forecast effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: The optimal amount is like any model hyperparameter, you need to find it yourself. Each model and each data is different, and it's impossible to have a ready answer.

But in general:

- Too short: not enough data, won't learn
- Too long: may be too much processing for very little gain (or even loss)

Question 2: Yes, you'd get improvement from using the sliding windows, because you have more data for a better generalization. (Unless your original dataset was already so long that it was good enough)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response